# Company wanted me to fill a personality test, I consequently lied, what now?

Tags: germany, law, test, personal-questions

So they wanted it from me as part of my initiation. I dislike if they try to dig in my brain. So instead the true answers, I used my job interview experience to estimate, which answers would they like better. And I have given consistently that type of answer.

If I could not decide, then I have given in about half the cases the true answer and about in half of the cases the opposite.

Fortunately, I can see the result. As I expected, it gives in about 50% of the truth and 50% of what I try to help them to think about me. In general, it deviates from my true personality exactly into the direction where I want to show myself on the job market. And that I find wonderful. They wanted to dig in my brain and I tricked them to see what I want from them to see in me.

Problem is that I lied. Intentionally. Consistently.

Is there some hidden risk in this behavior?

Comment: Other than proving how clever you are because you can "trick" this test, what's your actual goal here?

Comment: @iLuvLogix HR has got a work psychologist guy from South Korea and probably he wants to support personal decisions with his findings. So I want to show him that I match very well the team.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I think liar means someone whose habit is to lie. That is not my habit in general. I did it now. And, if employer has a honest moment before a mirror while shaving, I think he must admit, I had all the reasons to do that.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I suspect, personal decisions will be directly or indirectly affected by the results and I want to cover that I am actually not a good team player. That they will see, I do not want to prove them also by a test result.

Comment: If you were not comfortable taking the personality test, have you communicated that to HR?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki It had not been a good idea. They had seen that most people filled out the test, except GraySheep who rejected it (or tried to reject it). HR is not your friend, HR is the friend of the company, you know?

Comment: Why didn't you just refuse to do the test?

Comment: @red-shield It had been a bad start.

Answer (score 15):

> Problem is that I lied. Intentionally. Consistently.
> Is there some hidden risk in this behavior?

There is no "hidden" risk. There is the very obvious risk that they use your answers to somehow categorize you to determine either your work or which teams or colleagues you may want to work with. And then you get stuck in a category that you actually don't like, because you lied.

It's like lying when asked for your favorite meal. If you answer "beans" because you think that's what they want to hear, the very obvious risk is that they serve you beans for the forseeable future. If you like beans, great. If you hate beans, that's bad. But it's on you. They cannot really do much more than ask you.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from nvoigt nicely covers the obvious risks, but I'm not certain there are no hidden risks. Aspects of the test could have been designed to lead people to select answers and adopt behaviours that they thought were what the examiner wanted to hear.

If you're familiar with the [Honesty-Humility Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honesty-humility_factor_of_the_HEXACO_model_of_personality), it's possible that these aspects either weren't there, or were particularly well hidden. If you (or any candidate for the tests) were not familiar with this model, these could have appeared to be hidden.

If the personality tests included markers for honesty and dishonesty, it's possible you gave a far more accurate depiction of your personality than perhaps you intended.

Comment: Yes I was dishonest - but note: they have tried to dig into the brain of the employee without their consent. No, it was NOT an optional thing, probably I could have rejected it if I want to, and they had probably accepted that, but I can safely close out that it had had a for me positive effect to their personal decisions in the future. In general, I think I am honest. This time I was not, because **I could not**.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you had taken the personality test under oath, the questions are usually a matter of opinion and emotion - "Would you rather X or Y", or "Do you get upset easily", etc - therefore you could simply say your opinions and mental state have changed since the test due to the work environment, current events, mental health, or just on a whim. Assuming your test was like that, then you shouldn't be liable for your answers. (not a lawyer)

That said, if you acted as a total extrovert for the test, and then at work are reclusive and disinterested in others, then it would be no different than putting on an act for an interview. Depending on how much your personality affects the position will determine the consequences; for example, the company may place a higher importance on having the right personality type for a managerial position or a teacher than for a janitor.

Edit: After re-reading the question, I realized that OP said this was part of "initiation" - I assume that means *after* being hired. I'm guessing that either OP hadn't been placed on a team yet, or their position within the team hadn't been determined, and this was part of figuring that out. So, instead of manager or janitor, it would just be which project or what team dynamic you would get along well with.

Comment: Of course OP wouldn't be liable for answers on some mumbo-jumbo personality tests. It seems some companies rather burn money on useless things instead of paying their personal better

Comment: Yes that is right. I have seen strong hints that the primary users of the test result are the team leads. I can not see any effect of the test result to their decisions.

Answer (score 1):

The company I work for has a similar practice.  It is a company in the business of acquiring other companies, and selling the software products of all its acquisitions as a package to its customers.  One of the companies it acquired produced questionnaire software like what you describe, and that questionnaire software is marketed towards current and prospective customers as a way to improve employee satisfaction and productivity. Ostensibly the questionnaire results are aggregated and the report presented to management. In this way a manager may get a broad picture of how company-categorized working personalities (think analogous to Myer-Briggs?) are represented across their peers and subordinates, and can tailor management style and business decisions to make use of this information.

I do not think our company has any customers who have purchased this software product by itself, but it is included as a package deal with many others that have a more justifiable business value.

Perhaps my company encourages its use internally to lift the spirits of the people maintaining the product.

Ultimately, your manager will get to know you better through normal interaction than from a personality test. I don't think that being dishonest on such a questionnaire will have long term effects on your career,  but I also don't think that answering honestly would have been problematic or dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no concrete risk.
While we don't know about the exact questions, personality tests in general are not factually questions where your lies could be found out with hard evidence. If there is really somebody following up with "inconsistencies" between your test and your actual behaviour a short answer like "i don't know what info you could extract from such a vague personality test" should suffice.

As a fellow german, i never had to deal with such a personality test and like you dislike such practice. If i were in your shoes i would have outright refused to take this test. If that would have displeased the company or lost me the job, so be it. Because now you have already compromised your boundaries, when it's better to be clear about that early on to discover a potential mismatch between your values and company culture.

Comment: If you lose your job in **Probezeit**, that is not good signature in your CV. Anyways the job is quite a good one and I am a little bit surprised on your self-trust on the job market. Yes we are paid well, but I would not say that we find the job we like easily. Ok, I am an auslander, but afaik it is not very easy also for you.